# Accessing Public Property of the Site Master from a different .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my Site.Master.vb file, I have a custom `User` object:

```
Public Class Site
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Public Property u as User

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        u = New User

        u.loggedIn = True 'Just as an example
End Class
```

Now in one of the content pages, I want to be able to see if a user is logged in. I figured if the object `u` was declared in the Site Master, I could use it in the pages that derive from the Site Master. For example, I want to do:

```
...
<% If u.loggedIn Then %>
    <!-- display some HTML button here, ONLY if the user is logged in -->
<% Else %>
    <!-- display something else, if the user is logged out -->
 <% End If %>
```

Is there some other method that allows this to be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference of the [`Page.Master`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) - you will need to cast it to the type of the master page in order to access the custom property.

You can do this in a property of your own page for ease of use.

Comment: Seems like I just had to add `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>` to the .aspx page and then I could access the user by `Master.u`.

Comment: @LoganSerman - Well, the page would have to use a master page in order to access it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a **masterType directive** to your contentPage. Then you can access your public property **typed**.

```
<%MasterType VirtualPath="~/PATH_MASTER_PAGE/yourMasterPageName.master" %>
```

And within your **contentPage.vb**

```
if Pager.Master.u.loggedIn then
  ' do something
else
  ' do something else
end if
```

hth

Answer (score -1):

For me it's better if you use session-variables or viewstate server side, like

Session["loggedIn"] = true